# undecidable formulas and duality

Tags: logic

In *The Classical Decision Problem* (Gurevich et.al.) the authors state that first order formulas with the prenex $\forall\exists\forall$ are an undecidable class but those with prenex $\exists\forall\exists$ are a decidable class. Yet in Kleenes's *Metamathematics* he says that, by duality, for a sentence of a given form  one can always find a logically equivalent sentence by interchanging all occurrences of $\land$ and $\lor$ and all occurrences of $\forall$ and $\exists$.  But that seems to imply that sentences in the undecidable class above can be transformed into decidable ones by simply using duality, which in turns seems to imply the ones in the first class aren't really undecidable. If that's not the case, then what have I gotten wrong?

Comment: You are forgetting the NOT.

Comment: The NOT doesn't matter; if you include it ( i.e. negate every individual term)  you simply get a formula that is the logical equivalent of the negation of the original sentence, and so the puzzle remains: if you can decide an equivalent of the negation of the original sentence then can't you can decide the original sentence?

Comment: The NOT does matter: a first-order sentence and its negation can both be unprovable. E.g., you can design a sentence that says the universe of discourse has two elements. This is true in some structures but not in every structure.

Answer (score 0):

> first order formulas with the prenex ∀∃∀ are an undecidable class

False! The set of **all first-order formulae** with a certain prenex form is **decidable**.

However, the original statement is probably that the set of all **true** ∀∃∀-formulae is undecidable. Here "true" means "true in all models". Note that some formulae are true, some are false, and some are neither (in the sense that they are true in some models but false in others). This is precisely why negating does not transform one decision problem into the other, since the two sets of formulae are not complements.